# How to get an IFTTT action in Google Sheets to trigger a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ifttt

I have an IFTTT applet that will update cell C65 in my google sheet. I'd like that sheet to run a function submitData() whenever cell C65 is changed. As many know, however, the onEdit and onChange functions do not trigger from IFTTT actions, only from manual inputs.

I've learned this from searching for answers, and nobody seems to be able to explain a workaround. The strangest thing here is that when I first put it together today, it actually worked perfectly. I then swapped google accounts and made other changes that didn't relate to the code or IFTTT applet and all of a sudden it stopped working entirely, even when switching back to the correct google account.

This is the onEdit code that works for screen inputs but not when my IFTTT enters a value into the cell:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var cellAddress,cellAddressToTestFor;

  cellAddressToTestFor = 'C65';

  // Get cell edited - If it's C65 then do something
  cellAddress = e.range.getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellAddress: ' + cellAddress);

  if (cellAddress === cellAddressToTestFor) {
    //To Do - Code here if cell edited is correct
    submitData();
  };
}
```

Is there any way to get the IFTTT event to trigger my submitData function?

Comment: IFTTT puts the value to the Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. So in this case, I thought that the OnChange event trigger could be used. So from `onChange functions do not trigger from IFTTT actions`, can I ask you about the method that you have tried the OnChange event trigger?

Comment: I used the same code but substituted onChange. As I understand it though, onChange doesn't support the e.range call, so I don't know how to check the changed value's location to verify it's at C65

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that you might misunderstood about the OnChange event trigger. From your replying, I thought that you had been trying to use the OnChange event trigger as the simple trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) But, `onChange()` is not the simple trigger. So can you use the OnChange event trigger as the installable trigger and test it again? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: How do you mean? I'm not sure how to use an installable trigger, or what that is

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In this case, how about checking the official document at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable as shown in my replying? I think that English of the official document is better than me. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: You are better at English than I am at any of my other languages, so please don't feel bad about it! I appreciate your help so far, and I will read up on this! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your previous replying, when you used `function onEdit(e){}` as `function onChange(e){}` without installing the event trigger, the function of `onChange` cannot be fired as the trigger. So I proposed to use `onChange` as the installable trigger. About the method for installing the OnChange event trigger, you can see it at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). How about this?

Comment: Alright I set the function onChange() to an On change event trigger, but the sheet still doesn't do anything. I tried setting it to an On edit trigger as well, and it still didn't change anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. And I cannot understand about your current situation from your replying. So in order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? Because I can confirm that when the OnChange event trigger is installed as the installable trigger, the installed function is fired by the trigger when the values are put from IFTTT. By correctly understanding about your current situation, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Are you getting an execution of the function at all when data is inputted from IFTTT? Check out the [execution log](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/executions).

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. The on Change installable trigger DOES work when I use IFTTT. The failure is in the code. I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'getA1Notation' of undefined
    at onIFTTTChange`

So there must be some other way of finding the event object's cell location, right?

Comment: I got it! The event object for on Change contains no range property, so instead I used this:

`function onChange(e){
  var cellAddress,cellAddressToTestFor;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  // Get cell edited - If it's C65 then do something
  cellAddress = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Tanaike, I would have given up on this if you hadn't encouraged me!

Answer (score 0):

So the 'on edit' trigger won't work with IFTTT changes, but the 'on change' installable trigger will. However, the event object passed by the On Change trigger does not contain 'range', so there's no way to easily check the edited cell's location. To do so:

```
function onChange(e){
  var cellAddress,cellAddressToTestFor;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName();

  cellAddressToTestFor = 'C65';

  // Get cell edited - If it's C65 then do something
  cellAddress = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log('cellAddress: ' + cellAddress);

  if (cellAddress === cellAddressToTestFor) {
    //To Do - Code here if cell edited is correct
    submitData();
  };
}
```